# How to replace value in column of dataframe?

Tags: python, dataframe

anyone can guide me about python code for the replacement of the value of the data frame to some specified value. I have tried the dataframe.replace() method

```
data.replace(to_replace=['A','B','C' ], value=[2, 3, 4])
```

It works fine..

But when I tried with the collection it does not work with no effect on the dataframe.

```
d = [{'A': 2, 'B': 3, 'C': 4}]; # d is dictionary     
for key, val in d.items():
        data.replace(to_replace=[val] , value=[key])
```

Anyone can help me that why this is not working?

Comment: `d` is not a dictionary, it is a list that contains a dictionary. `for key, val in d.items():` should throw an `AttributeError`.

Comment: Have a look at the examples in [the documentation for `.replace()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) - you can use a dictionary as an argument without looping over its items.